# How can a Java Socket read() take a long time when it returns -1 and is finished?

Tags: java, sockets

I am doing some benchmarks on a HTTP server. To avoid potential conflict with HTTP libraries, I open the connection directly using a Socket, with no HTTP persistent connections.

The Java code opens and connects an `InputStream` on a socket connected to a loaded HTTP server.  It is running on Linux.

I see that that either of these could happen:

- The socket connect (new Socket()) could take long. This makes sense if the server has a backlog in accepting new connections.
- The socket connect is fast but the delay, up to 1500 milliseconds, is in the last read when read() returns -1 to signify the stream is at the end of "the file." This I do not understand.

The code follows the standard, with some timing code added:

```
final byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int size = inputStream.read(buffer);

while (size > 0) {
    // Copy the buffer
    size = inputStream.read(buffer);
}
```

Comment: What version of the HTTP specification do you claim compliance with? And what are the exact headers that you send?

Comment: I would expect to see this behaviour if the output stream is not closed and is just discarded.  The Socket will be finalized and closed on the next GC but when this happens in unpredictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The socket connect is fast but the delay, up to 1500 milliseconds, is in the last read when read() returns -1 to signify the stream is at the end of "the file." This I do not understand.

Assuming that the scenario is exactly as you've explained; i.e. that you simply connected to port 80 and tried to read data:

- The server is most likely waiting for your client code to send a request.
- The server times out the read after 1.5 seconds, and then it closes both sides of its socket.
- That results in the client-side socket seeing an EOF ... which is signalled to your code by returning `-1` from the `read(...)` call.

Basically, your code has to send a well-formed HTTP request to the server if you expect the server to send you a response.

On the other hand, if your code *did* send a well-formed HTTP request, then the behaviour could be caused by your code trying to read more data that the server has to send ... combined with sending a Request that specified a persistent connection (see HTTP 1.1  spec, [section 8.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1)).

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `read` after you've already received all the data the server is going to send. This is a mistake. Once you've received the full reply (as determined by the HTTP protocol), you should stop calling `read`. You are waiting for the connection to timeout, which is silly.

The HTTP protocol tells you when you have received the full reply, not the TCP protocol. You are expecting the TCP stack to understand HTTP. It does not. It has no idea when you've received a full reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when receiving a response with a JSON body. After several experiments, I detected that program hanging while reading the body. So, I solved this, by reading Content-Length from the header, stopping after the blank line ( which between header and body ), and reading only necessary characters after that. Here is code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class TelegramSocketClient {
    private final String CONTENT_LEN = "Content-Length:";
    Socket clientSocket;
    SSLSocket sslSocket;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    public void startSSLConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory
                .getDefault();
        sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(ip, port);

        out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public String sendMessage(String msg) throws IOException {
        out.println(msg);
        String line = null;
        int contentLen = 0;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line.startsWith(CONTENT_LEN)) {
                contentLen = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(CONTENT_LEN.length() +1, line.length()));
            }
        }

        char [] buff = new char[contentLen];
        in.read(buff, 0, buff.length);
        return new String(buff, 0, buff.length);
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```